# Ada fixed-point rounding of multiplication

Tags: ada, fixed-point

The following code prints `TRUE` that means `0.0191*0.0191` is evaluating to `0.0003` and `0.0192*0.0192` is evaluating to `0.0004`. However:

```
0.0191*0.0191 = 0.00036481
0.0192*0.0192 = 0.00036864
```

Had the rounding happened at the threshold of `0.00035`, the corresponding threshold for square root should have been `0.0187`.

If I change the delta to `10.0**(-5)`, this is not the case.

So my question is "How rounding of fixed-point calculation works in this situation?"

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type T is delta 10.0**(-4) range 0.0 .. 10.0;

   X1 : T := 0.0191;
   X2 : T := 0.0192;
   Y : T := 0.0004;
   B : Boolean;
begin
   B := (X1 * X1 = Y - T'Delta) and (X2 * X2 =Y);
   Put_Line(B'Image);
end Main;
```

Comment: Have you tried to take a look in the Ada Reference Manual?  I'm pretty sure it contains an explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don’t think that 'rounding' is quite the problem here.

You say

```ada
type T is delta 10.0**(-4) range 0.0 .. 10.0;
```

which means (`Put_Line (T'Small'Image);`) that the least significant bit of a `T` is 6.103515625E-05.

This is the first binary power of 2 less than the delta; [ARM 3.5.9(8)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-5-9.html#p8) merely requires it to be less than or equal to the delta.

So, 0.0191 is represented as 312 in binary, which multiplied by `'Small` gives 1.904296875E-02, which squared is 3.62634658813477E-04, which divided by `'Small` to get the binary representation is 5.94140625E+00. GNAT uses the permission in [ARM 4.5.5(21)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-4-5-5.html#p21) ("for ordinary fixed point types, if the mathematical result is between two multiples of the small, it is unspecified which of the two is the result") to convert this to 5, which corresponds to 3.0517578125E-04, giving your 0.0003 result when rounded for printing.

0.0192 is represented as 314 in binary, which leads to a result of 6.017822265625E+00, converted to 6, which corresponds to 3.662109375E-04, rounded for printing to 0.0004.

You'll have gathered that I messed around with your code to get these numbers!

You might want to consider

```ada
Delta_T : constant := 10.0 ** (-4);
type T is delta Delta_T range 0.0 .. 10.0 with Small => Delta_T;
```

Comment: Or use a decimal fixed-point type: type T is delta 10.0 ** (-4) digits 6 range 0.0 .. 10.0;

Comment: Insightful and detailed. Thanks a lot.